# VSCode highlight Flutter errors but Android Studio does not

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I have simple Flutter project with following files:

```dart
abstract class TableData {
  String createdAt;
  bool deleted;
  String id;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  TableData(this.createdAt, this.deleted, this.id, this.updatedAt);
}

class Listing extends TableData {
  String name;
  Listing (this.name, {String createdAt, bool deleted, String id,  DateTime updatedAt}) : super(createdAt, deleted, id, updatedAt);
}

abstract class AListingRepository implements ARepository<Listing>{

  Future<List<Listing>> getAll({bool includeDeleted : false});
}
```

Now while the code compiles and runs from both VSCode and Android Studio, VSCode is complaining about **Listing** not extending **TableData** in the **AListingRepository** declaration.  There is a squiggly under Listing in that declaration (abstract class AListingRepository implements ARepository<**Listing**>) and when I hover over it, it says **[dart] 'Listing' doesn't extend 'TableData'**.  What gives?

Comment: Did you enable `--preview-dart-2` in one of them? What Flutter version are you using? Screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Running flutter v0.1.5 on WIndows.  Dart Code extension installed in VSCode is version 2.11.0.  I am brand new to VSCode.  How do I enable --preview-dart-2?  I believe that means a preview version of Dart.  What does that do?  Does it have to do with changes in Dart 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it enables some upcoming/experimental changes for Dart 2.

Comment: OK, how do I check if its enabled and why do I get these errors in VSCode and not Android Studio (yet the code compiles and runs in both).

Comment: @Igor I can't repro this is it possible you could raise an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues or shout me (DanTup) in Gitter so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: Also, FWIW - beta branch appears to have been updated so running `flutter upgrade` and then restarting VS Code (or running `Reload Window` from the command palette) is worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is simpler than one may have thought.  So I started out with a Flutter project in Android Studio.  After I have defined some folders, I have opened the folder in VSCode and it was giving me all that grief described above.

Well it seems like eithe VSCode or Android studio have replaced "folder/file" imports with "package" imports which seems to have worked OK in Android Studio but not in VSCode.  Once I update those imports back to "folder/file", all is good in VSCode.

BTW, I have just updated Flutter (and Dart SDK) to the latest by running Flutter upgrae but the problem persisted after that.

Comment: VS Code shouldn't change any imports automatically; but there was a bug on Windows due to case-sensitivity and VS Code providing us lowercase Drive letters. This is hopefully all be fixed in the latest version of Dart Code!